# Beep at resuming from suspend

Tags: 12.10, kernel, suspend

Since the upgrade from Precise to Quantal, the kernel beeps (quite loud) when waking from suspend. Is there a way to disable the beep?

Answer (score 1):

You can try disabling the kernel module that is responsible for creating the beeps. Just edit the file `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf` and add the lines

```
blacklist pcspkr
blacklist snd_pcsp
```

If you save the file and reboot your PC should not beep any more. Consider that your PC doesn't beep any more at all. This might be what you want, but if not, this is not the right way for you.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, it is preferred to add the essential parts of the answer here, and add the link for reference. Should the list stop working, your answer would not help future users.